# How to migrate AWS ECS from one account to another (in a different Region/AZ)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Docker containers are hosted with aws ecs inside a VPC in a particular region. How do I migrate them to a different VPC in a different region?

Comment: You have to completely recreate them. There is no "move" function for things like this. Hopefully you used something like CloudFormation or Terraform to create them, so redeploying them to a different region will be as simple as changing the region ID in your IaC.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB. That was my initial thought process. However I wanted to check if there could be any other way.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there isn't a straightforward method to migrate a service from one region to another. To accomplish this, you'll need to ensure that you have a VPC and ECS cluster set up in the target region. Then, you can create the service within that cluster and VPC.

If you're using Cloudformation or Terraform for configuration as code, simply update the region and relevant definitions, then redeploy. Otherwise, you can use the AWS CLI to extract the full definition of your cluster and service, and then recreate it in the target region. For more information, see the AWS CLI ECS reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/index.html

Also, make sure that any Docker images stored in a private registry are accessible in the target region. Best of luck with your migration!